# No se visualiza formulario html5 con internet explorer 11

Tags: html5, navegador-web, internet-explorer-11

Tengo montando un formulario que funciona perfectamente en todos los navegadores pero al visualizarlo en internet explorer 11 observo que no se visualiza bien.

**Asi lo quiero**

[image: Esto es correcto]

**Asi sale en Internet Explorer**
[image: Esto es incorrecto, se ve así cuando lo cargo en explorer 11]

```html
<p class="left entradaTxt">
  <!-- <p class="pull-right entradaTxt"> -->
  <label for="Fotografia">Fotografía (tamaño máximo 500 Kbytes, formato .jpg):</label>
  <input id="foto" name="FotografiaJPG" type="file" accept=".jpg" class="input-file-jpg" size="500">
</p>
```

Cómo puedo solucionar éste problema ya que no veo nada al respecto.

Gracias por los aportes de antemano.

Comment: Hola Kike deberias añadir la imagen de lo que te sale con IE11 para quien no pueda verlo

Comment: Sí, lo he he hecho com el móvil, ya que lo tengo probando en otro equipo con un windows.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias.

Comment: Ya lo he probado, no funciona. De todos modos muchas gracias por los aportes.

Answer (score 1):

> Todo navegador tiene unas líneas guía respecto a cómo deben verse los controles en base a la plataforma en donde se ejecuten.

No puedes hacer que se vean igual un `input file` en todos los navegadores, del mismo modo que no puedes hacer que se vean igual un `select`. Esto sucede porque tienen un motor diferente de renderizado; si tienes dos navegadores con el mismo motor verás que no hay diferencias en cómo renderizan los componentes. En adición, cada navegador agrega un "estilo por defecto" a los controles.

**Solución**

En navegadores basados en *Webkit* y en *IE* tenemos a disposición la propiedad CSS `webkit-appearance`. Hay una larga lista de posibles valores (puedes verlas [aquí](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/)) pero para eliminar la apariencia que le da el navegador por defecto se usa el valor `none`:

```
input[type="file"] {
  webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Sin embargo, en varios escenarios no obtenemos el resultado deseado. En estos casos, lo que hay que hacer es un **control personalizado**.

```js
function putFilename(filename, node) {
  node.textContent = filename;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,700');


body {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="file"] + label {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  /border-radius: 3px;
  color: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans';
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

input[type="file"] + label + p {
  color: #555;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans';
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-file">
  <input type="file" id="file" onchange="putFilename(this.files[0].name, filename)">
  <label for="file">Seleccionar</label>
  <p id="filename">No se ha escogido ningún archivo</p>
</div>
```

Así mantienes una vista única sea el navegador que sea, lo cual es bueno para una mejor UX.